# How to show or hide a DIV programmatically in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar with several buttons that make divs appear underneath.

```
<a data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#select" role="button" aria-controls="select"></a>
<div id="select" class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="false">
    Foobar
</div>
```

I also need to open these windows programmatically. For example, if I initially use `$('#select').collapse('show')` nothing happens.

However, if I first click on the A tag and then execute the line of code `$('#select').collapse('toggle')` I am able to hide/show the window. However, if I try to click on the A tag again, it tells me

> Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.collapse

Roughly speaking, I should add the class "show" to the div with id="select" and then set "visibility: visible"; to the div. However then clicking again on the A tag skips a loop, and I have to click twice to make the div disappear again.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @StepanMichalek I must display that div without clicking on the A tag, I must do so programmatically while being consistent with the Bootstrap toggle cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you are mixing Bootstrap’s `collapse` and `offcanvas` functionalities.
Since you’re using `offcanvas`, you should use Bootstrap’s `offcanvas` API methods rather than the `collapse` API.
For example:

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('select'); 
var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas); 
bsOffcanvas.show(); 
// To hide the offcanvas 
bsOffcanvas.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can show elements using `$("#something").show();` and hide with `$("#something").hide();`

Comment: I've already tried, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this-

Keep track of a flag where it changes to true or false each time you click. Use the CSS properties in the function whether to display or not.

HTML-

```
 <a data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" onclick="changeflag()" href="#select" role="button" aria-controls="select">Select</a>
    <div  id="select" class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="false">
    Foobar </div>
```

In  tag,

```
<script>
        var flag=false;
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("select").style.display = 'none';
        };
   
      function changeflag(){
          if(flag==false){
              
              flag=true;
              console.log(flag);
              document.getElementById("select").style.display = 'block';
          }
          else if(flag==true){
              
              flag=false;
              console.log(flag);
              document.getElementById("select").style.display = 'none';
          }
          
      }
  </script>
```